# AS3. How to push enemy step by step while during animation?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, actionscript, frame

I'm creating flash game. Here is main player Hero and Enemy. This is fully animated game, but I have issue that when Hero during attack animation It should push enemy back by ~100 px step by step. 
For now I got:

By clicking "x" key It starts attack animation and It straight off set Enemy's x coordinates to +/-100 px.

Here is about 100 frames and I need to make that while during animation it step by step pushed enemy back (In first frame -1 px, in second frame -2px, in 57th frame -57px etc...).

Here is code:

```
if (Hero.leftx <= enemyRight && (Enemy.hitTestObject(Hero))) //here check if Hero have collision with Enemy 
                        {
                        Hero.gotoAndStop("attack" + attack); //start attack animation   
                            Enemy.x += 100; //here push enemy by 100px
                            currentHPenemy -=  10;
                        }
```

Have you ideas?

As I understand I need to make something like, but I don't know how to make It correctly:

```
if(currentFrame != totalFrames) {
Enemy.x += 100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set a velocity on your enemy and make it move every frame by that velocity * frameLength.

Comment: Thank you for answer, could you give me a code example, please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In your enemy class have a hitBack() function that adds an Event.ENTER_FRAME listener to your movieclip and sets a counter to 0. On the enterframe function, make this enemy's x position increment by 1, then when the counter reaches 100, remove the EVENT.ENTER_FRAME listener.

```
public class Enemy 
{
    private var count = 0;

    public function hitBack()
    {
       count = 0;
       this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, myEnterFrame);
    }

    private function myEnterFrame(e)
    {
       if (count == 100) this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, myEnterFrame);
       else 
       {
          count++;
          this.x += 1;
       }
    }
}
```

then you would call it like this

```
enemy.hitBack();
```

Might have to adjust a line or two, it's off the top of my head.

Comment: Thank you for answer, could you give me example how to make It?